# PowerShell ways to extract / modify cookie information

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, firefox, cookies

I'm hopeful that someone here may have addressed this and I think various peopole could see the usefulness. I'm on a Windows system so ideally, I'd like to do this with PowerShell.

My goal is to be able to query the cookies from Chrome or Firefox to see what they are and when created etc. From this, I might be able to do a variety of things, such as:
• Delete all Amazon cookies
• Delete all cookies between given dates
etc.

We can do these things within Chrome itself (i.e. I can open up the "All Cookies" setting in Chrome, search for matches and delete them) but it would be massively more convenient to have some PowerShell to have complete control over cookies from PowerShell.

I have googled on this extensively found no solutions. e.g. the following unfortunately only deal with IE or maybe Edge (and no one really uses either in my experience - also Edge is about to be replaced with the new Chromium-Edge, which is a *great* browser and makes Edge actually usable, so a Chrome solution would probably apply to Chromium-Edge too).
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-my-internet-cookies/

Any leads into doing this would be appreciated.

Comment: Chrome stores cookies in a SQLite db file called 'Cookies' (no extension) in your profile which can be found `"$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"`.  
Firefox does this in a file called `cookies.sqlite` you can find in this location: `"$env:APPDATA\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"`.

In both cases,the cookies themselves are stored as **record** in a SQLite database, not as separate files somewhere.

Comment: You may be able to find extensions per browser that let you edit the cookies, like [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) for Google Chrome or [Cookie-Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/cookie-editor/) for Firefox. **_These are just the first hits in Google.. I have not tested these extensions myself_**

Comment: Thanks @Theo, these are good leads. A programmed method would be best. I had read that Chrome used a db file somewhere. If both as SQLite db's, will be great if we can run SQL queries against them to remove selected cookies. Doing some searches around this to see if I we are allowed to get into those files (i.e. they might be encrypted :( ). https://duckduckgo.com/?q=access+chrome+sqlite+cookies&atb=v194-1&ia=web

Comment: Yes, but even if you succeed there, Chrome (most notably) could complain after changing the cookies that its data has been tampered with..

Comment: Chrome cookies are encrypted. I think this is a lost cause.

Comment: You are probably right. Maybe some genius will come across this question with a brilliant solution, but probably not. I guess in the meantime I will use AutoHotkey to open the correct Chrome settings dialogue, then automatically input the cookie search to delete then do that. It's quite useful for various sites that block you after viewing five pages etc, so I should be able to whip something up with AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 0):

We have a solution here :
https://github.com/techthoughts2/ApertaCookie/tree/main

The project is no longer maintained and was removed from the PS Gallery, but i just tested it under Chrome and it works real fine !

I had to update the Cookies file location ($env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Network\Cookies)

Sample code :

```
Import-Module -Name "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\ApertaCookie-main\src\ApertaCookie\ApertaCookie.psm1" -Force
$session = Get-DecryptedCookiesInfo -Browser Chrome -Verbose
$session | ? { $_.host_key -eq "myWebsite.fr" -and $_.name -eq "myCookieName" }
```